# Moving Hyper-V virtual disk to SMB share gives file not found error in the end

Tags: hyper-v, network-attached-storage, server-message-block, vhdx

I want to move some virtual disks to from an old ISCSI disk (old NAS) to a new SMB share but for every disk it gives a file not found error in the end and gives the location of the disk on the SMB share as file not found location.

Whether I move a virtual disk from a local disk on the host server or from the ISCSI disk makes no different. They give the same error in the end. I'm moving them using the Move feature of the Hyper-V Manager and have also tried manually moving them and updating the location in the Manager

Is there are advice on what's possibly causing this?

The NAS is a 2U Synology Rack set up in SMB 2.0 and higher mode. Plenty of space on the share (and NAS). The server is Windows 2012 R2

Comment: Perhaps you can tell us how you're moving them and what OS the Hyper-V server is running?

Comment: @joeqwerty I added the requested details

Comment: How are you moving the files?

Comment: @joeqwerty With the "Move" feature in the Hyper-V Manager application

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> The NAS is a 2U Synology Rack set up in **SMB 2.0** and higher mode. Plenty of space on the share (and NAS). The server is Windows 2012 R2

SMB 2.xx is your problem. You need SMB 3.xx to allow Hyper-V running VMs from your file share.

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/yungchou/2012/09/10/windows-server-2012-hyper-v-over-smb-explained/

Comment: Could be the reason perhaps, but the maximum version of SMB is set to 3.0 in Synology, so it should be available to the server. Maybe I should force that version to be sure it's used

Answer (score -2):

It could be that locations have to be mounted as a drive before they can be used to host Virtual Disk files.